# How to make preview for each file input with filereader

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make preview for each file input. I have three file upload like this. I want preview of this input' upload preview for each.. I don't know how to use this. function on DOM element. Thank All.

```
<div class="app">
          <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
          <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
</div>

<div class="app">
          <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
          <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
</div>

<div class="app">
         <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
         <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
</div>

<script>
function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById(this."uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Try like this .........

[html javascript image preview before upload-- code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: Yes, This is preview for one file input upload, i want to konw how to preview for 4 file input with one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the sample JS code using jquery:

```
function readURL(input, img_id) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#'+img_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".img-up").change(function(){

    readURL(this, $(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="img1" class="img-up" data-id="img_view1" />
    <img id="img_view1" src="#" alt="your image" />

    <input type='file' id="img2" class="img-up" data-id="img_view2" />
    <img id="img_view2" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

The input file `data-id` and `img` tag `id` must be same. Hope you will understand see this code.

Comment: i want to get for four input file. I already test for this. This work for one file input. Thk

Comment: Please check my updated answer this will help you :) @MaungYeHtunZaw

Comment: http://codepen.io/maungyehtunzaw/pen/LGbdEO     your code is at here, it not work. pease check what i need to do. I just test on codepen to show you.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/prabuguna/oqyfvu8c/) I think you need to add JQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/prabuguna/oqyfvu8c/

Comment: have you got it now?

Comment: Yes Thank, i got it from above link. what version of jQuery i need to link?

Answer (score 0):

[Upload Preview jQuery Plugin](http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/)

How it works?

To get access to the not uploaded data, we can use the HTML5 file reader api. This api provides reading local files. This step is pretty important, because we need to this data in order to show it in the browser window. To get more information about the file reader, you can read the [offical documentation.](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <input type="file" class="" name="img" id="uploadImage" onchange="PreviewImage()" />
    <div class="image_uploaded" id="image_uploaded">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;
    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.id = "uploadPreview" + counter;
            img.src = oFREvent.target.result;
            var src = document.getElementById("image_uploaded");
            src.appendChild(img);

            counter++;
        };
    };
```

I hope it will help someone.