# How to get file url of front end uploaded file

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

--UPDATE--

So I am attempting to create a file previewer that allows someone to upload files with on the front end, access the browser files as a blob, and preview them in an iframe.

**MUST BE ABLE TO PREVIEW ALL OPEN DOCUMENT FILES**

My current issue is that **viewer.js** (http://viewerjs.org/instructions/) doesn't seem to work with blob files. This was the closest information I got..https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS/issues/230

Any ideas on a way to have this work with all open document files? Plugin recommendations?

Current Code below..

```
    fileUploadProcessFiles: function(fileInput){
            console.log("MODALJS.fileUploadProcessFiles");
            var m = $(document).find("#modal"),
                list = $("#uploadList"),
                files = fileInput.files,
                type = m.find("option:selected").text();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // Display List
                list.append(`<div class='hundredWidth'>"+
                                <label class='autoWidth underline'>${type}</label><label class='cancelIconSmall inlineBlock' onclick='MODALJS.fileUploadRemoveFile(this)' style='margin-left: 10px'></label>
                                <label class='oneWide'>${files[i].name}</label>"
                          </div>`);

                // Store Preview Links
                var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
                MODALJS.fileUploadPreviewLinks.push(blobURL);
                // Append Iframe Preview
                list.append(`<iframe src="${MODALJS.fileUploadPreviewLinks[i]}" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>`);
                // Push to upload queue
                MODALJS.fileUploadFiles.push(["file", files[i]]);
            }
        },
```

--UPDATE #2--

So I got it figured out. I had to use a different plugin. webODF instead... I should be able to cobble together a decent enough solution now.

```
fileUploadProcessFiles: function(fileInput){
            console.log("MODALJS.fileUploadProcessFiles");
            var m = $(document).find("#modal"),
                list = $("#uploadList"),
                files = fileInput.files,
                type = m.find("option:selected").text();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // Display List
                list.append(`<div class='hundredWidth'>"+
                                <label class='autoWidth underline'>${type}</label><label class='cancelIconSmall inlineBlock' onclick='MODALJS.fileUploadRemoveFile(this)' style='margin-left: 10px'></label>
                                <label class='oneWide'>${files[i].name}</label>"
                          </div>`);

                // Store Preview Links
                var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
                MODALJS.fileUploadPreviewLinks.push(blobURL);
                // Append Iframe Preview

                list.append(`<div id="odfCanvas"></div>`);
                odfElement = document.getElementById("odfCanvas");
                odfcanvas = new odf.OdfCanvas(odfElement);
                odfcanvas.load(blobURL);
                // Push to upload queue
                MODALJS.fileUploadFiles.push(["file", files[i]]);
            }

        },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523227/how-to-make-preview-for-each-file-input-with-filereader

Answer (score 4):

There is no URL for an uploaded file. At least not in the traditional "resource locator" sense. You can access the file via the `FileReader.result` property.

This snippet is more or less [directly from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). Added a few comments to clarify (hopefully) what's happening where.

```js
function previewFile() {
  const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
  const file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  // listen for 'load' events on the FileReader
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // change the preview's src to be the "result" of reading the uploaded file (below)
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  // if there's a file, tell the reader to read the data
  // which triggers the load event above
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img id="preview" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

**Update for comment question:** PDFs are tricky. Well, anything that isn't natively rendered in the browser is going to be tricky or impossible. You might try [`URL.createObjectURL(file)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and then making that the source of an iframe to trigger the browser's not-quite-native-per-se PDF rendering. You could also try Mozilla's [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/)

Comment: So you're saying that if I wanted to preview a non image file, like a pdf I will always have to store it on a server... because there is no resource locator.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Updated the answer

Comment: I'm not familiar with viewer.js but a search for 'filereader' at their github repo only turned up a single unanswered ticket. :( https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS/issues/179. You might try using `URL.createObjectURL(file)` to create a URL and stuffing it into (and re-initializing) a viewer.js link.

Comment: Thanks, Will I think creating the object url is getting warmer. I'm just not sure if it will work with a blob url.. so far no luck. This viewer is the best though because it does all open document formats instead of just a pdf. I need to ultimately preview a variety of files, then convert to pdf with timestamp and save in DB after submission. I'm going with the viewer trying to avoid a db hit ahead of time. I will keep investigating and will update if I find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Looks like `readAsDataUrl` is what you want.